# AHK in Visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, autohotkey

I'm using a shortcut to remind me to use two equal signs to check for equality. heres my AHK code:

```
::if::
      Send, if 
      MsgBox Use two equal signs to check for equality!
Return
```

When I type 'if' it will bring up the box and keep the if the first time, after that it eats up the 'if' and doesn't print it. The code works fine for any other application but I can't get it to work in Visual Studio 2013. Also, it seems to work as expected when I try it in a comment. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attaching the [option](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#Options) `B0` to a hotstring prevents it from removing the previously typed phrase, so you don't have to re-send `if` again:

```
:B0:if::
      MsgBox Use two equal signs to check for equality!
Return
```

Comment: hey that worked! Thanks! I can't accept your answer for another 7 minutes

Answer (score 3):

I know you already have your answer, but I personally would hate a MsgBox every time I typed "if". You may want to look into using [context sensitive hotkeys](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm). Furthermore, instead of a MsgBox, you could use a less invasive ToolTip. This way, you could keep typing but still get notified.

```
CoordMode, Caret, Window
:B0:if::
    ToolTip, Use two equal signs to check for equality!, % A_CaretX, % A_CaretY+20
    Sleep, 3000
    ToolTip
return
```